# Use index of values in each bin of a histogram to bin other arrays in python

Tags: python, for-loop, data-binding

I am binning some data using `np.hist`, i.e. `histo, edges = np.hist(array, bins=100)`. Now, I need to use the indices of the data points in each bin to get the equivalent values from some other arrays (named for example `array1`, `array2`, ..) to get 100 (i.e. nbins) sets of values. If this was the case of a single bound, I could easily do

```
ia = np.where((array>=edges[lower]) & (array<edges[upper]))
xa = list(set(ia[0]))
new1= array1[xa]
new2 = array2[xa]
...
...
...
```

But I can't find an efficient method to do it for the binned data. Is there a way to do this?

Edit:

After much looking around, I found a rather inelegant solution.

```
dict_ = {}

for i in range(len(bins)-1):
    ii = np.where((array>=edges[i])&(array<edges[i+1]))
    xx = list(set(ii[0]))
    dict_[i] = xx

new_lst = []
for val in dict_.values():
    new_lst.append(val)
```

The variable `new_lst` is a list of indices listed for each bin. Finally, doing

```
for i in range(len(new_lst)):
    hh = list(set(res[i]))
    array1_select = array1[hh]
    ...some operation...
```

This seems to do the trick for now. However, if someone as a more efficient solution, let me know.